# InAppBrowser build cannot find symbol

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, inappbrowser

I'm building a Cordova App from VS2017 with Tools for Apache Cordova, the app is deadly simple, it uses:

- Cordova 6.3.1
- node.js 443
- npm 1.15.0
- cordova-simulate 0.3.13
- cordova-android 5.2.1
- cordova-ios 4.2.0
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.1.0
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2

config.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget defaultlocale="it-IT" id="com.test.test" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
  <name>Test</name>
  <description>Test</description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">test</author>
  <vs:template-name>BlankJS</vs:template-name>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
    <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
    <icon height="30" src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
    <icon height="310" src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="44" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
    <icon height="106" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
    <icon height="70" src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
    <icon height="71" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
    <icon height="170" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash height="480" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="960" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1024" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="2048" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="768" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1536" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1136" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash height="300" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
    <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~3.1.0" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="True" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
  <vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
  <engine name="android" spec="~5.2.1" />
  <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.0" />
  <engine name="windows" spec="~4.4.2" />
</widget>
```

when I build Android I get:

> 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :
>   c:\DemoApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java:1190:
>   error: cannot find symbol 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : 
>   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N) 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  ^
>   1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  symbol: variable N 1>MSBUILD :
>   cordova-build error :  location: class VERSION_CODES 1>MSBUILD :
>   cordova-build error :
>   c:\DemoApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java:268:
>   error: cannot find symbol 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  if
>   (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
>   1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  ^ 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :
>   symbol: variable O 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  location: class
>   VERSION_CODES 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :
>   c:\DemoApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java:272:
>   error: cannot find symbol 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : 
>   ((InAppBrowserClient)inAppWebView.getWebViewClient()).waitForBeforeload
>   = false; 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  ^ 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  symbol: method getWebViewClient() 1>MSBUILD :
>   cordova-build error :  location: variable inAppWebView of type WebView
>   1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :
>   c:\DemoApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java:1191:
>   error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  @Override 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build
>   error :  ^

I have the following Android SDK's:
[image]

I tried to use the VS `Take latest patch` check and to update cordova-android to 8.0.0 from CLI, but Visual Studio still shows 5.2.1 in thr GUI and the issue remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I have to set the usage of the global cordova version and not the sandboxed:
[image]

then I set the min api level:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

and remove android platform:

```
cordova platform remove android
```

and add it again:

```
cordova platform add android
```